# configure error of emacs for scala

Tags: emacs, elisp

I followed the procedure from http://jawher.net/2011/01/17/scala-development-environment-emacs-sbt-ensime/ in order to configure emacs for scala.

However, I encountered an issue of during

```
(require 'scala-mode)
```

because in scala-emacs/scala-mode-constants.el, it was referecing

```
(let* ((charmap (make-char-table 'case-table))
```

and it complains `unrecognized char table type: case-table`

I am wondering if anybody can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using XEmacs, whereas the Scala-mode code only works under Emacs.